# RequestsLibrary on an API using OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, robotframework

I am trying to use RequestsLibrary on an API that's using the OAUTH2 authentication, but every time it throws 400! =200.

```
Get authToken

    Create Session   test   http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/
    ${data}=      Create Dictionary     grant_type= 'password'      client_id=demoapp     client_secret=demopass      username= 'demouser'   password='testpass'
    ${headers}=     Create Dictionary   Content-Type= 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ${resp}=  post request     test     /lockdin/token     ${headers}     ${data}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${resp.status_code}     200
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As the oAuth server is inaccessible can you modify the example to use an online test oAuth server? This way we can help you better.

Comment: @ A.kootstra I updated example with demo oauth server but now I am getting 404. I am not sure where I am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used extended request library instead of request library

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ExtendedRequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Post Request With Password

    Create Password OAuth2 Session    member    http://token     client_id    client_secret    username   password    scope   base_url
    ${var} =  get request        member    /abc
    Log    ${var.content}
```